# How to set the same route template in different controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, routes, asp.net-core-webapi

I got a code from another team, this is a .net core 2.2 web api with a controller : `CustomerDemandController` and I have to create another one (`ManagerDemandController`) with pretty much the same methods in it. In both of the controllers, I have a "Get by Id" method. which looks like this :

```
[ApiVersion(Constants.LatestVersion)]
[Route("api/{version:apiVersion}/[controller]/")]
[ControllerName("customerdemands")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[EnableCors("SiteCorsPolicy")]
public class CustomerDemandController : ControllerBase
{
    private const string GetByIdOperation = "GetById";

    [Get("{id}", Name = GetByIdOperation)]
        public async Task<ActionResult<CustomerDemandResponse>> GetAsync([FromRoute] string id)
            => await this.GetAsync(() => Service.GetByIdAsync(id),
                                   ConversionHelper.Convert);

    ...
```

(same method in the other controller with ManagerDemandResponse as response).
Now that I have added the new controller, I want to test if the old one still works and this is not the case anymore due to the same route name "GetById" in both controllers.

> System.InvalidOperationException : The following errors occurred with attribute routing information:
>
> Error 1: Attribute routes with the same name 'GetById' must have the
>   same template: Action:
>   'DemandManagement.Api.Controllers.CustomerDemandController.GetAsync
>   (DemandManagement.Api)' - Template:
>   'api/{version:apiVersion}/customerdemands/{id}' Action:
>   'DemandManagement.Api.Controllers.ManagerDemandController.GetAsync
>   (DemandManagement.Api)' - Template:
>   'api/{version:apiVersion}/managerdemands/{id}'

How can I have the same templates as the controller name is different ?

Comment: The issue is the route name not the template. Change the route Name. That needs to be unique to avoid route conflicts

Comment: Do you mean I should have "GetCustomerDemandById" and "GetManagerDemandById", for example ?

Comment: Yes that is easier to understand and has a clearer intent.

Comment: I included a link to the docs that explain it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the route name and not necessarily the template. Change the route Name. Route Names should be unique to avoid route conflicts.

```
//...
public class CustomerDemandController : ControllerBase
{
    private const string GetByIdOperation = "GetCustomerDemandById"; //<-- Unique

    [Get("{id}", Name = GetByIdOperation)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<CustomerDemandResponse>> GetAsync([FromRoute] string id)
            => await this.GetAsync(() => Service.GetByIdAsync(id),
                                   ConversionHelper.Convert);

    //...
```

> Route names can be used to generate a URL based on a specific route. Route names have no impact on the URL matching behavior of routing and are only used for URL generation. ***Route names must be unique application-wide.***

*emphasis mine*

#### Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core : Route Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#route-name)